# Wordpress REST API "orderby" meta value

Tags: wordpress, rest, api

I am execting following GET request to obtain data form wordpress

```
http://domain:port/wp-json/wp/v2/announcement?_fields=announcement_category,effective_start_date,effective_end_date
```

The result is as below

```
[
    {
        "announcement_category": [
            216
        ],
        "effective_start_date": "2020-03-27",
        "effective_end_date": "2020-04-16"
    },
    {
        "announcement_category": [
            215
        ],
        "effective_start_date": "2020-03-25",
        "effective_end_date": "2020-03-31"
    }]
```

I need to sort/order my response in the ASC order of the "announcemet_category" value. (there is always one value for this array)
I know "orderby" does not support meta_values. 
How to enable meta_value sorting and how can I execute my query for this.
Please help

Comment: This looks like what you're looking for: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/218724/52230

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to sort on a meta value using:

```
$q = new WP_Query(
    // Other query params e.g. post type...
    array(
        'meta_key' => 'announcement_category',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'ASC',
    )           
);
```

Based on [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/218709/order-by-custom-field-value).

However I think your issue is that as you've pointed out, `announcement_category` is an array rather than a number, which you won't be able to sort on.

If you can't change `announcement_category` to a number rather than an array, you can use a [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort the results of your WordPress query, before sending the API response:

```
$arr1 = array(
    array('announcement_category'=>array(216)),
    array('announcement_category'=>array(218)),
    array('announcement_category'=>array(202)),
    array('announcement_category'=>array(300)),
);

function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a['announcement_category'][0] - $b['announcement_category'][0];
}

usort($arr1, 'sortByOrder');

print_r($arr1); // Ordered ascendingly
```

Alternatively, you can use javascript on the client side to sort the response as required:

```
announcements.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a[announcement_category][0] - b[announcement_category][0];
});
```

[Array Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. According to your advice, I have tried the wp REST call as below
[link](announcement?_fields=announcement_category,effective_start_date,effective_end_date&filter[orderby]=meta_value_num&filter[order]=ASC&filter[meta_key]=announcement_category).
I'm getting an empty result.

Comment: I don't think that's going to work - you'd need to change your data structure so announcement_category is a number rather than an array. I have added a usort example to my answer - I believe this is the best solution.

Comment: Thanks, In my case, "announcement_category" is a taxonomy and cannot change into a single number. So my plan is to order the results with java after receiving the wp response.

Comment: That's another approach, but I'd suggest reordering with a usort on the results of your wp_query, before but before the API response is returned. Otherwise anything that accesses the API will need to reorder the response

Comment: Is adding "usort" configured in WP side?
I do not have permission to do so. I only can GET data using REST API.

Comment: Yes you'll have to order the response at your end then